# Do we need to keep the [homework] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I recently noticed that we have a [homework](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag here on AI.SE. I'm not sure exactly when it was created, but this tag doesn't seem like a useful tag to me, for basically the same reasons that [Stack Overflow got rid of the homework tag ten years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123758/294691).

The tag does not describe the content of the question; it describes where the question came from. While the fact that it's homework can occasionally be useful - especially when determining if something is plagiarism - a tag is not a useful way of determining that. People don't generally want to sort explicitly homework questions, because there's no particular uniting factor aside from their origin. The topic can vary wildly.

This doesn't seem like a useful tag; does anyone have any objections to burninating it?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking it is the [advice on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=homework+tag) to not allow the [homework](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag (mostly applicable to SO), ***but*** there is an important exception: [some sites prohibit full answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165683/282094) to homework questions.

Of course, should we disallow the tag, [moderators can ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19018/282094) the tag's usage.

This is the [first non-closed usage](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10910/17742), it seems helpful; as indicated by the discussion there.

Here are three examples were someone added the tag with an edit ([1](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/14032/17742), [2](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21879/17742), [3](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21885/17742)), and then went on to offer what looks to be a complete answer; @Nbro may have thoughts on the usage of the tag.

Other than that, the early usages of the tag seem helpful, assuming that we don't want to do people's homework for them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this tag can be useful, and I think it should be kept, independently of the consensus on this topic that we see in meta or other SE sites. It doesn't really harm the site.

The reason why I think it should be kept is simple:

> clearly, many of our visitors are students, and we may not want to give them the full answers to their homework problems/questions.
>
> Students may reformulate their questions in ways that do not look like homework questions and, in general, it may not be easy to distinguish a homework question/problem from a non-homework one, but, if someone decides to use this tag, they want to let us know that we probably shouldn't give them the complete answers, although one could still do that.

Nevertheless, I don't really have a very strong opinion on this topic. If you want to remove it, it wouldn't also harm much the site.

Answer (score -1):

- [Quantum Computing has the "textbook-and-excerices" tag](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/textbook-and-exercises).
- [Chemistry has the "homework" tag](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) but it has been deprecated.
- [Physics has the "homework-and-exercised" tag](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework-and-exercises) and it has **22,000+ questions**.
- I didn't see any "homework" or "exercises" tag on Mathematics, but I'm not sure if the search was just taking too long to work.

If the homework tag here is burninated, it shouldn't be because SO burninated it, nor should it be for "basically the same reasons" as the ones SO used to justify burninating it. The tag should be burninated only if the ***consensus*** within ***this specific specific community*** is to do so.

Luckily, the [homework](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag here at AI only has 19 questions and 0 watchers so far, so it wouldn't be a big deal to burninate it, but I think the reason to do so has to be a good one (not just "SO did it so we will do it too").